# How to handle tvOS MenuBarTemplate selection?

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

I have a basic MenuBarTemplate set up and displaying.

How do I react to a user's Menu selection and load an appropriate content template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `menuItem` tag include a `template` attribute pointing to the template to load and a `presentation` attribute set to `menuBarItemPresenter`.

```
<menuItem template="${this.BASEURL}templates/Explore.xml.js" 
  presentation="menuBarItemPresenter">
    <title>Explore</title>
</menuItem>
```

You can then use the menu bar's `MenuBarDocument` feature to associate a document to each menu bar item.

```
menuBarItemPresenter: function(xml, ele) {
  var feature = ele.parentNode.getFeature("MenuBarDocument");
  if (feature) {
    var currentDoc = feature.getDocument(ele);
    if (!currentDoc) {
      feature.setDocument(xml, ele);
    }
  }
```

This assumes you're using a [`Presenter.js`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Listings/client_js_Presenter_js.html) file like the one in [Apple's "TVML Catalog" sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). The `load` function specified there is what calls the function specified in the `menuItem`'s `presentation` attribute.

Comment: I'm trying to handle some logic as XHR loading a feed for an stack template. Anybody knows how to handle this inside a MenuBar? Everything I'm trying now doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that TVML and TVJS is similar with HTML and Javascript. When we want to add some interaction into the user interface, we should `addEventListener` to DOM.

In Apple's "TVML Catalog", Presenter.js is a nice example, but it is abstract, and it could be used in different Present actions.

When I develop my app, I had wrote this demo for handling menuBar selection.

Module : loadTemplate.js

```js
var loadTemplate = function ( baseURL , templateData ){
  if( !baseURL ){
    throw("baseURL is required");
  }
  this.BASEURL = baseURL;
  this.tpData = templateData;
}

loadTemplate.prototype.loadResource = function ( resource , callback ){
  var self = this;
  evaluateScripts([resource], function(success) {
      if (success) {
          var resource = Template.call(self);
          callback.call(self, resource);
      } else {
          var title = "Resource Loader Error",
              description = `There was an error attempting to load the resource '${resource}'. \n\n Please try again later.`,
              alert = createAlert(title, description);
          Presenter.removeLoadingIndicator();
          navigationDocument.presentModal(alert);
      }
  });
}

module.exports = loadTemplate;
```

Module nav.js ( use menuBarTemplate ) :

```js
import loadTemplate from '../helpers/loadTemplates.js'

let nav = function ( baseURL ){

  var loader = new loadTemplate( 
      baseURL , 
      {
        "explore" : "EXPLORE", 
        "subscribe" : "SUBSCRIBE", 
        "profile" :  "PROFILE", 
        "settings" : "SETTINGS" 
      }//need to use i18n here 
  ); 

  loader.loadResource(`${baseURL}templates/main.xml.js`, function (resource){

    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var navDoc = parser.parseFromString(resource, "application/xml");

    navDoc.addEventListener("select" , function ( event ){
      console.log( event );

      var ele = event.target,
      templateURL = ele.getAttribute("template");

      if (templateURL) {
        loader.loadResource(templateURL,

          function(resource) {
            if (resource) {
              let newParser = new DOMParser();
              var doc = newParser.parseFromString( resource , "application/xml" );

              var menuBarItemPresenter = function ( xml , ele ){
                var feature = ele.parentNode.getFeature("MenuBarDocument");
                if( feature ){
                  var currentDoc = feature.getDocument( ele );
                  if( !currentDoc ){
                    feature.setDocument( xml , ele );
                  }
                }
              };

              menuBarItemPresenter( doc , ele );
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });

    navigationDocument.pushDocument(navDoc);

  });//load from teamplate.

}

module.exports = nav;
```

My code is not the best practice, but as you can see, you just need to `addEventListener` like you are writing a web application. Then you can handle `menuBarTemplate` selection easily, even after XHR loading.

Avoid too many callbacks, you should rebuild your code again and again. :-)

Comment: You can use Promise :-)